# Bigtable shell hangs on any command

Tags: hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to follow [Google Cloud Bigtable tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-shell-quickstart).

I reached the point when quickstart.sh launches and shows the prompt,
but it hangs on any command. I tried `list` and `create`.

Comment: The quickstart has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts to play with APLN and JVM versions I found that there are  N + 1 way exists how Bigtable can break.

There is a trick which worked out for me.
I put the surefire plugin with APLN jar.

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19</version>
       <configuration>
           <argLine>-Xbootclasspath/p:${settings.localRepository}/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/${alpn.version}/alpn-boot-${alpn.version}.jar</argLine>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I run with jdk8 profile (I have 1.8.60).

```
mvn -Pjdk8 clean package exec:exec -Dbigtable.projectID=pid \
    -Dbigtable.clusterID=cid -Dbigtable.zone=z
```

Comment: Sorry for your troubles.  We'll fix the quick start.  The client is indeed a bit difficult to set up due to the use of secure HTTP2 transport, which is a relatively new protocol.

We'll fix the quick start.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here on this StackOverflow question as a newcomer to BigTable. I failed to understand when reading the [Bigtable Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart) page that it was a way to shortcut installing HBase on my machine and that you actually just run `quickstart.sh` in CloudShell hosted in a browser.

So, if you end up here because, like me, you failed to realize that [Bigtable Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart) page is saying, run `quickstart.sh` in Google CloudShell, then maybe I have helped by writing this!

Thank you to [Les Vogel - Google DevRel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738710/les-vogel-google-devrel) for realizing my simple mistake.

If you want to interact with Google Bigtable on your machine, my original answer still applies. I'll leave my answer because my own idiotic commentary below entertains me and deleting the answer would delete the commentary.

---

To install HBase on your machine, the instructions are, basically, set up your Google Cloud Account, Enable Billing, Enable API access, Enable BigTable, download `gcloud` shell, download HBase, configure HBbase.

These instructions worked well

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell

Comment: Kirby - what machine were you on?

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel, "MacBookPro11,5" El Capitan 10.11.16. Thank you for responding

Comment: If you still have your folder from the Quickstart, could you give  me the version of the bigtable.version in the pom.xml?

Comment: Also, you were running on your MBP, not on CloudShell?  It should run on a Mac using ./quickstart.sh

Comment: Hah! What a dunce I am! You're right, I was running on my computer. I failed to understand that I was supposed to run quickstart.sh in CloudShell. Somehow I interpreted that the quickstart.sh was a way to emulate CloudShell and that establishing CloudShell was a necessary precursor to running quickstart.sh on my machine.

Comment: Actually, it should work on both places.  It works on my mac, I'd like to understand why it doesn't on yours.  That said, it's not really your problem - it should just work everywhere.  Do you have maven installed on your Mac?  brew install maven ??

Comment: ok. Yes, I have mvn v3.3.9, installed via brew; jdk1.8.0_74.jdk, installed via brew; bigtable.version v0.9.2 in quickstart/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it again, but it works on my Mac.  I install via brew as well. I'm on 1.8.0_91 b14.  k - I'll see if I can reproduce. My understanding is that your problem is solved.